# How to grant jenkins user permission to access a specific directory on linux

Tags: linux, jenkins, user-permissions

I need to grant jenkins user permission to access some specific directories like `usr/lib` or `usr/local/include` so that he can copy some files into those directories during the execution of some Jenkins jobs. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea that something accessed from the web can overwrite system files is very scary (and insecure), but I think you would need to grant the user under which Jenkins is running the privileges need to write there.

Again, *there are good reasons why ordinary user's aren't granted permissions to write to those directories*.  You might want to consider running the job in a [chroot jail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot).  That way, if something goes wrong, you won't destroy your system.

Answer (score 0):

For specific task i would say use `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned `usr/lib` or `usr/local/include` directories, and if your goal is to install some tools and packages during job execution, you could install it locally into your job workspace (for example, into `.local` directory) and after that make your jobs work with those directories by setting environment variables like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `CFLAGS`, etc.